# Is there a way to reuse mongodb connections so the server doesn't crash when there are too many cloud instances writing ina a collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, cloud, connection-string

I have a small python cloud function in GCP that validates a json file and then writes the content to MongoDB. The connection code is outside the callable in the cloud function, so I though that same object would be used across all instances. However, the server crashed when it hit the connection limit and now I'm wondering if there's anyway to either reuse the connection object to MongoDB or disable the opening of a pool and change it to just one connection, so there are as many connections as instances (in my case there were 5x connections as there were cloud instances).

The connection code is outside the callable in the cloud function, so I though that same object would be used across all instances. I have read some answers available but they're all related to AWS/Azure that have mechanisms to deal with this, or they're written from a web application and not a cloud function.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **maxPoolSize** on the **mongoClient** to the desired connection number per cloud function instance and set a max number of instances for the cloud function.

Mongo doc here for maxPoolSize https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#mongodb-urioption-urioption.maxPoolSize

Max number of instance in cloud function here
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/max-instances?hl=es-419#guard_against_excessive_scale-ups